# PHP - Same structure arrays not working with function

Tags: php, arrays

Everything works fine if i use this structure:

```
function create_order_with_custom_products()
{
    $orderGenerator = new OrderGenerator();
    $orderGenerator->setCustomer(6907);

    $orderGenerator->createOrder(array(
        // Add configurable product
        array(
            'product' => 30151,
            'qty' => 1
        ), array(
            'product' => 30150,
            'qty' => 2
        ),
    ));
}
```

If i create an array and use it like that:

```
$ItemsId = [];
if(!empty($ItemsInCart) && count($ItemsInCart)>0)
{
    foreach($ItemsInCart['productid'] as $key=>$value){
        $ProductId = $value;
        $ProductQty = $ItemsInCart["productqty"][$key];
        $product_id = $ProductId; // Replace id with your product id
        $qty = $ProductQty; // Replace qty with your qty

        $ItemsId[] = ["product"=>$ProductId,"qty"=>$qty];
    }
}




function create_order_with_custom_products()
{
    $orderGenerator = new OrderGenerator();
    $orderGenerator->setCustomer(6907);

    $orderGenerator->createOrder($ItemsId);
}
```

If i `print_r($ItemsId);` i receive the following output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [product] => 30143 [qty] => 1 ) [1] => Array (
>   [product] => 30144 [qty] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [product] => 30145
>   [qty] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [product] => 30146 [qty] => 4 ) [4] =>
>   Array ( [product] => 30147 [qty] => 5 ) )

It is no longer working. And i do not see the reason.

The code of `createOrder` function you can see here: http://pastebin.com/0iUbZpHU

Can you please tell me where is my mistake and why my code is not working.

Comment: Aside: `!empty($ItemsInCart) && count($ItemsInCart)>0` is redundant. Ideally that should just be `$ItemsInCart` (i.e. `$ItemsInCart == true`). If you don't know whether the variable exists (→ why?!), you may do `!empty($ItemsInCart)`. Both cases already cover the `count() > 0` case.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The `$ItemsId` variable is not available inside the `create_order_with_custom_products()` function. You'll need to pass it as a parameter:

```
function create_order_with_custom_products($ItemsId)
{
    // ...
}
```

And then call it with the variable you created:

```
create_order_with_custom_products($itemsId);
```

Comment: Do i have to change anything else inside the `create_order_with_custom_products` function itself?